# Google Script runtime limitations

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

So the question is:
Is there any limit of total script runtime per day? Didn't find answer at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

And whats the difference between Custom function runtime and Script runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the script is run manually, it can be run for 6 minutes per execution. There is no  documented total quota on the total runtime per day. If the script is triggered, you're limited to total runtime of 90min/day(to 6hrs/day)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! And if the script is deployed as a webapp and executed by click of a button on the site, is it classified as a trigger or as manual launch?

Comment: @Vladimir I believe `doGet` and `doPost` are simple triggers. But I haven't tested and I do not know for sure.

Comment: In the result I measured before, in that case, the script is manually run by the user set with `Execute the app as:`. So in this case, it is not included in the time-driven trigger.

Comment: @TheMaster Welcome. If I noticed that the specification is changed, I would like to report it.

Comment: Why am I getting the timeout in 30 seconds? The document shows that it is a Custom Function. But what a Custom function actually is? I am getting timeout in 30 seconds because I have to click a button on the card at the right side of the g-suit addon i created. What I have to do for achieving a 6 min timeout?